# Background image (Logo) gets hidden when I put another image

Tags: beamer, floats, backgrounds, logos

I am making a latex beamer presentation. The blank slide (with logo of a lion in background) looks like as shown  [image: Fig]

Now, I want to add an image of a figure to this slide. When I add the figure to slide, the background logo gets hidden as shown in the second Figure here [image]

However, I do not want to hide the background logo of tiger. The background logo should also be completely visible along with the image. Please guide me for a possible solution.

The code  is given as follows:

```
 \documentclass[compress, xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics [width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{slide_bg.png}}
    \begin{document}
        \section{Model order reduction of commensurate fractional order systems}
        \subsection{Proposed approach}
        \begin{frame}[t]{\bigskip \Large \vspace{-5mm}Model order reduction of commensurate fractional order systems }
            \textbf{Proposed approach}
            \begin{figure}[![enter image description here][3]][3]
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[height=4.4cm]{LFC121.jpg}
                \vspace{6mm}
                \caption{Block diagram of single area power system with controller}
            \end{center}
            \end{figure}
        \end{frame} 
    \end{document}
```

Also, the figures used in the above code are also attached below
[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe you can use some sort of 'multiply' blending option.

Comment: Please suggest how to do it

Comment: I do not know how to do it in LaTeX, but that is the technical term you should use.

Comment: If you don't want to hide the background, you probably should not put another image with a white background on it. Irony aside, the best solution would be to draw the chart in Ti*k*Z. This way, you would only display the lines and characters on the background.

Comment: Cant draw using tikz. I have so many of such images that i want to put

Comment: Wouldn't PNG be better than JPG for that kind of image? Then you can make the PNG transparent.

Comment: Yaa i can use png. How to make png transparent?

Comment: BTW, it's not possible for "the background logo should also be completely visible along with the image".  One has to be in the foreground and the other in the background.  For example, if you have a red bar in your slide, do you want it to cover the gray background?  Or do you want the gray artwork to cover the red bar?  I guess you want the white portions of your lion logo to be transparent, but for the gray to cover your slide?

Comment: @James I want the lion logo to be visible, wherever the image has a white portion

Comment: @ShJ: I understand.  So my answer below is not exactly what you want then.  My solution would lead to portions of your slides being obscured by the gray portions of the lion logo.

Comment: Yes, Thanks for your reply but I also want something that could work with TexStudio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem seems to be that you are using a `jpg` file, [which cannot be transparent](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/130824/33180) and hence cover the background image.

Your code works fine as it is, provided the image in the figure is transparent (typically, a `png` file):

```
 \documentclass[compress, xcolor=table]{beamer}
\usebackgroundtemplate{\includegraphics [width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{example-image}} % Courtesy of mwe package
    \begin{document}
        \section{Model order reduction of commensurate fractional order systems}
        \subsection{Proposed approach}
        \begin{frame}[t]{\bigskip \Large \vspace{-5mm}Model order reduction of commensurate fractional order systems }
            \textbf{Proposed approach}
            \begin{figure}[![enter image description here][3]][3]
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[height=4.4cm]{PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png} % Courtesy of https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png
                \vspace{6mm}
                \caption{Block diagram of single area power system with controller}
            \end{center}
            \end{figure}
        \end{frame} 
    \end{document}
```

[image]

(You need to download [this file](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png) and place it in the same folder as your source code for this example to compile).

Simply add transparency to your file: you can use [gimp](https://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2016/09/gimp-how-to-make-a-transparent-background/) to do that, or you can look for [solutions on-line](https://onlinepngtools.com/create-transparent-png).

Comment: With Gimp and by using png, it works superbly

Answer (score -1):

The pdftk command line program has the `stamp` and `background` arguments that are useful for placing an image either behind or in front of your slides. For example, I have a "draft" stamp in draft.pdf with transparent background. I apply this stamp to a my presentation pdf file as follows...

```
pdftk presentation.pdf stamp draft.pdf output draft_presentation.pdf
```

You will want your stamp pdf file to be the same page size as your presentation.  Also, it will need a transparent background.  Good luck!

Comment: I am using TexStudio with MikTex. How do I implement the above solution, please suggest

Comment: @ShJ: I run pdflatex from a batch file, so the pdftk command is just added to my batch file and gets run each time I compile my pdf.  I'm sorry, but I've never used TexStudio.